# How does Scala deal with recursive return types?

Tags: scala, recursion

In OCaml there's this thing called 'rectype' which allows recursive return-types. To illustrate what I mean by that here's a method with such a type:

```
def foo(n: Int)(i: Int): ??? = {
  val m = n + i
  (foo(m), m)
}
```

The question is; what do you put in `???`'s place? Looking at the code you'd think it's something like:

```
Int => Int => (Int => (Int => (Int => (Int => ... , Int)
```

Why? Because the type of `foo(m)` is `Int => (Int => rep, Int)` where `rep` in the tuple is the repeated structure.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, Scala has recursive types (but perhaps not the kind you're looking for). Take `List`, for example (abridged to relevant parts):

```
sealed abstract class List[+A] ...

final case class ::[B](head: B, tl: List[B]) extends List[B] ...

object Nil extends List[Nothing] ...
```

`List(1, 2, 3)` is recursively defined from multiple lists using cons `::`.

```
1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil
```

Or without infix notation:

```
::(1, ::(2, ::(3, Nil)))
```

---

I *suppose* you could represent the type this way. But notice you have to define the type yourself:

```
sealed abstract class Inf[A]

case class Func[A](_1: A => Inf[A], _2: A) extends Inf[A] with Product2[A => Inf[A], A]

object Identity extends Inf[Nothing]

def foo(n: Int)(i: Int): Inf[Int] = {
    val m = n + i
    Func(foo(m) _, m)
}
```

Or a little more specifically:

```
def foo(n: Int)(i: Int): Func[Int] = {
    val m = n + i
    Func(foo(m) _, m)
}

scala> val f = foo(5)(3)
f: Func[Int] = Func(<function1>,8)


scala> f._1(10)
res8: Inf[Int] = Func(<function1>,18)
```

Comment: I need to create the infinity monad!! No one says it HAS to be infinite, it just needs to promise that it _is_ infinite somewhere down the line. That could probably done with lazy typing

Comment: It is possible to create an infinite series using the `Stream()` collection.  With a self-referential definition you can have things like a stream of primes, Fibonacci numbers, factorial values, etc.  I don't know how close that would get you to a real infinity monad.

Comment: What do you use `Identity` for?

Comment: @ElectricCoffee In this example, I didn't actually. But if you ever want the recursion to stop.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, the return type would depend on the two input values `n` and `i`. Both of these are unknown at compile time (Scala is statically typed!), which means the compiler wouldn't know the static return type. This is obviously bad for numerous reasons.

In general, you can neither define recursive types, nor can you [utilize type inference for recursive methods](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/local-type-inference.html).

Comment: So basically there's no way of doing this at all

Comment: Nope. Also, not knowing the return type at the declaration site is a bad thing as well.

Comment: but you do know the return type. It's a recursive tuple! OCaml deals with this by making a closure behind the scenes (or so I've been told)

Comment: Strictly speaking, to say you cannot define recursive types in Scala is false. Just look at linked lists. There's a difference between strict possibility and whether or not the compiler can infer the type. It is true that the compiler cannot infer the type.